# Does MFRC522 supports native SPI of Arduino Due?

Tags: arduino-due, spi, rfid

Does [MFRC522 library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid) support native SPI interface of Arduino Due?

By native SPI I mean this one:
[image]

I came here with this question because the initializer asks for 2 pins: SS and Reset:

```
MFRC522(byte chipSelectPin, byte resetPowerDownPin);
```

SS pin can be any, but what about Reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why it wouldn't support the Due's SPI. It just uses the default SPI.h library as the interface.

The `resetPowerDownPin` can be anything you like. It is not part of the SPI protocol but specific to that library. It is just controlled with `digitalWrite()` internally.

If you don't want to use the functionality you can set it to `MFRC522::UNUSED_PIN` and it will be disabled.

Comment: I tested it, it actually works.

Comment: You have a typo, should be `MFRC522::UNUSED_PIN`.

Comment: @kelin Indeed it should. Well spotted.